# Angular8 drag and drop problem with drag and drop with multiple cases

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-dragdrop

I am working with Angular8 Drag and Drop and come across some problem

What is my concept and what I am doing

1. Truck in which I drag and drop deliveries
2. Deliveries in which I drag and drop packages
   this are working fine

I am using following JSON data structute(shown below) which is get updated with `moveItemInArray` and `transferArrayItem` function

```
trucks = [{
    "..": '',
    "Deliveries": [{
        "..": '',
        "Packages": [{

        }, {}, {}, ....]
    }, {}, {}, ....]
}, {}, {}, ....]
```

Everything works fine but I need some extra things to be applied with drag and drop that is,

1. I want a package to be directly dropped inside truck...so when a package is directly dropped into the truck I want to add a delivery object in that truck deliveries and then inside that delivery, I want to assign the drop package
2. I want delivery to be directly dropped inside the delivery...so when delivery is directly dropped I want to move all package of previous delivery packages to current delivery

I have tried a lot with different things but drag and drop get disturbed and miss behaves

Below are my ts and HTML template code

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

import { ModelTruck } from '../../core/models/model-truck';
import { ModelDelivery } from '../../core/models/model-delivery';
import { ModelPackage } from '../../core/models/model-package';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-manual',
    templateUrl: './manual.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./manual.component.css']
})

export class ManualComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() packages: ModelPackage[];
    @Input() trucks: ModelTruck[];
    @Input() deliveries: ModelDelivery[];

    /**
     * Trucks inside work area
     */
    workTrucks = [];

    /**
     * Deliveries drop inside trucks connected element IDs
     */
    truckIds = ['no-trucks'];

    /**
     * Packages drop inside deliveries connected element IDs
     */
    deliveryIds = ['no-delivery'];

    /**
     * Column from which we are applying filter
     */
    column: any = 'Km';

    /**
     * Direction use for filter ASC or DESC
     */
    direction = 1;

    /**
     * Choosed truck/delivery/package data
     */
    choosed = {
        '1': '-',
        '2': '-',
        '3': '-',
        '4': '-',
        '5': '-',
        '6': '-',
        '7': '-',
        '8': '-',
        '9': '-',
        '10': '-',
        '11': '-',
        '12': '-',
        '13': '-',
        '14': '-',
        '15': '-',
        '16': '-',
        '17': '-',
        '18': '-',
        '19': '-',
        '20': '-',
        '..': '..',
    };

    /**
     * Initializing constructor
     */
    ngOnInit() {

        this._createConnectedIds();
        this._calculateAllStuff();
    }

    /**
     * Creating connected link Ids for the drag and drop elements
     */
    _createConnectedIds() {

        // For the deliveries to be drag and drop
        for (let truck of this.trucks) {
            this.truckIds.push(`truck-${truck.ID}`);
            for (let delivery of truck.Deliveries) {
                this.deliveryIds.push(`delivery-${delivery.ID}`);
            }
        }

        // For the packages to be drag and drop
        for (let delivery of this.deliveries) {
            this.deliveryIds.push(`delivery-${delivery.ID}`);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Onchange sort by
     */
    doSort(sort) {
        this.direction = sort == 'ASC' ? 1 : -1;
    }

    /**
     * Onchange filter by
     */
    doFilter(filter) {
        this.column = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Event on drop the packages
     */
    onPackageDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
              event.container.data,
              event.previousIndex,
              event.currentIndex);
        }

        this._calculateAllStuff();
    }

    /**
     * Event on drop the deliveries
     */
    onDeliveryDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
              event.container.data,
              event.previousIndex,
              event.currentIndex);
        }

        this._calculateAllStuff();
    }

    /**
     * Event on drop the trucks
     */
    onTruckDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
              event.container.data,
              event.previousIndex,
              event.currentIndex);
        }

        this._calculateAllStuff();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate all the stuffs
     * Related to weight, volume, cost and number of packages etc
     */
    _calculateAllStuff() {

        this._removeDeliveriesWithoutPackage();
        this._calculateTrucksStuff();
        this._calculateDeliveriesStuff(this.deliveries);

        console.log('-----------------------');
        console.log('Trucks Inside The List');
        console.log(this.trucks);
        console.log('Trucks Inside Work Area');
        console.log(this.workTrucks);
    }

    /**
     * Remove deliveries without package
     */
    _removeDeliveriesWithoutPackage() {

        // Remove deliveries not contains package (Deliveries area)
        this.deliveries = (this.deliveries).filter(function(obj) {
            return obj.Packages.length != 0;
        });

        // Remove deliveries not contains package (Work Area)
        for( let truck of this.workTrucks ) {
            truck.Deliveries = (truck.Deliveries).filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.Packages.length != 0;
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate package related stuffs
     * Related to weight, volume, cost and number of pieces etc
     */
    _calculatePackagesStuff(packages) {

        let packageStuffs = {
            ActualWeightDry: packages.filter((obj) => obj.TypePackage === 'dry').length,
            ActualWeightCold: packages.filter((obj) => obj.TypePackage === 'cold').length,
            ActualWeight: 0,
            ActualVolume: 0,
            ActualCostMerchandise: 0,
            NumberPackages: packages.length,
            NumberPieces: 0
        };

        for( let item of packages ) {
            packageStuffs.ActualWeight += item.ActualWeight;
            packageStuffs.ActualVolume += item.ActualVolume;
            packageStuffs.ActualCostMerchandise += item.ActualCostMerchandise;
            packageStuffs.NumberPieces += item.NumberPieces;
        }

        return packageStuffs;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate deliveries related stuffs
     * Related to weight, volume, cost and number of pieces etc
     */
    _calculateDeliveriesStuff(deliveries) {

        let deliveryStuffs = {
            MaxCostMerchadise: 0,
            ActualWeight: 0,
            ActualVolume: 0,
            NumberDestinations: deliveries.length,
            ActualCostMerchandise: 0,
            NumberPackages: 0,
            NumberPieces: 0,
            Trip: 0
        };

        for( let delivery of deliveries ) {
            deliveryStuffs.MaxCostMerchadise += delivery.MaxCostMerchadise;
            deliveryStuffs.ActualWeight += delivery.ActualWeight;
            deliveryStuffs.ActualVolume += delivery.ActualVolume;
            deliveryStuffs.ActualCostMerchandise += delivery.ActualCostMerchandise;
            deliveryStuffs.NumberPackages += delivery.Packages.length;
            deliveryStuffs.NumberPieces += delivery.NumberPieces;
            deliveryStuffs.Trip += delivery.Trip;

            let packageStuffs = this._calculatePackagesStuff(delivery.Packages);
            let keys = Object.keys(packageStuffs);
            for( let key of keys ) {
                delivery[key] = packageStuffs[key];
            }
        }

        return deliveryStuffs;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate trucks related stuffs for both work and in list
     * Related to weight, volume, cost and number of pieces etc
     */
    _calculateTrucksStuff() {
        this._calculateForTruck(this.trucks);
        this._calculateForTruck(this.workTrucks);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate truck stuff
     * Resulable code
     */
    _calculateForTruck(trucks) {
        for( let truck of trucks ) {
            let deliveryStuffs = this._calculateDeliveriesStuff(truck.Deliveries);
            let keys = Object.keys(deliveryStuffs);
            for( let key of keys ) {
                truck[key] = deliveryStuffs[key];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recalculating time
     */
    doRecalcTime() {
        alert('Doing recalculate time[need to implement]');
    }

    /**
     * Recalculating the order
     */
    doRecalcOrder() {
        alert('Doing recalculate order[need to implement]');
    }

    /**
     * Choosed element
     */
    choose(elem) {
        this.choosed = elem;
    }

    /**
     * Choosed element keys only
     */
    choosedKeys() {
        return Object.keys(this.choosed);
    }

    /**
     * Check if object
     */
    isItObject(elem) {
        return elem instanceof Object;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="width-20 truck-lists">
        <div class="sorting">
            <div class="sort-filters">
                <select (change)="doFilter($event.target.value)">
                    <option value="">Filter By</option>
                    <option value="TypeVehicle">TypeVehicle</option>
                    <option value="MaxWeight">MaxWeight</option>
                    <option value="MaxVolume">MaxVolume</option>
                    <option value="Km">Km</option>
                    <option value="Cost">Cost</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="asc-or-desc" (change)="doSort($event.target.value)">
                <select>
                    <option value="">Sort By</option>
                    <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
                    <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul 
            cdkDropList 
            #truckArea="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="trucks" 
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[workArea]" 
            (cdkDropListDropped)="onTruckDrop($event)">
            <li 
                cdkDrag
                *ngFor="let truck of trucks | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}"
                class="truck-item"
                (click)="choose(truck)">
                <div class="truck-item-content">
                    {{ truck.TypeVehicle }} 
                    #{{ truck.ID }} | 
                    {{ truck.NumberDestinations }} Deliveries | 
                    {{ truck.NumberPackages }} Packages | 
                    {{ truck.Km }} Km | 
                    ${{ truck.Cost }}
                </div>

                <ol type="i">
                   <li *ngFor="let delivery of truck.Deliveries">
                       {{ delivery.State }}, {{ delivery.DestinationTR1 }}
                   </li>
                </ol>

                <span class="truck-size-tag">{{ truck.ID }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="width-60 truck-works">
        <div class="truck-works-dashboard">
            <ul 
                cdkDropList 
                #workArea="cdkDropList"
                [cdkDropListData]="workTrucks" 
                [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[truckArea]"
                (cdkDropListDropped)="onTruckDrop($event)">
                <li 
                    cdkDrag
                    *ngFor="let truck of workTrucks"
                    class="truck-item truck-item-in-dashboard"
                    (click)="choose(truck)">
                    <div class="truck-item-content">
                        {{ truck.TypeVehicle }} 
                        #{{ truck.ID }} | 
                        {{ truck.NumberDestinations }} Deliveries | 
                        {{ truck.NumberPackages }} Packages | 
                        {{ truck.Km }} Km | 
                        ${{ truck.Cost }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="truck-row">
                        <div class="only-deliveries">
                            <ul 
                                cdkDropList 
                                [cdkDropListData]="truck.Deliveries" 
                                cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" 
                                [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="truckIds" 
                                id="truck-{{ truck.ID }}" 
                                (cdkDropListDropped)="onDeliveryDrop($event)">
                                <li 
                                    cdkDrag
                                    *ngFor="let delivery of truck.Deliveries"
                                    class="delivery-item"
                                    (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); choose(delivery)">
                                    <div class="delivery-name">
                                        {{ delivery.State }} - {{ delivery.DestinationTR1 }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="delivery-time">
                                        {{ delivery.Delivery }}
                                    </div>
                                    <ul 
                                        cdkDropList 
                                        [cdkDropListData]="delivery.Packages" 
                                        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="deliveryIds" 
                                        cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"  
                                        (cdkDropListDropped)="onPackageDrop($event)" 
                                        id="delivery-{{ delivery.ID }}">
                                        <li 
                                            cdkDrag
                                            *ngFor="let package of delivery.Packages"
                                            [ngClass]="package.Type == 'Urgent' ? 'package-item urgent' : 'package-item'"
                                            (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); choose(package)">
                                            Pack #{{ package.ID }}<br>
                                            {{ package.Type }}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="only-dashboard">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Restriction</th>
                                        <th>Kg</th>
                                        <th>m3</th>
                                        <th>$</th>
                                        <th>Access</th>
                                        <th>Minutes</th>
                                        <th>Incomp</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Actual</th>
                                        <td>{{ truck.ActualWeight }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ truck.ActualVolume }}</td>
                                        <td>${{ truck.ActualCostMerchandise }}</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Max</th>
                                        <td>{{ truck.MaxWeight }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ truck.MaxVolume }}</td>
                                        <td>${{ truck.MaxCostMerchadise }}</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Available</th>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ truck.MaxWeight - truck.ActualWeight }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ truck.MaxVolume - truck.ActualVolume }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            ${{ truck.MaxCostMerchadise - truck.ActualCostMerchandise }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>%Available</th>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="truck-size-tag">{{ truck.ID }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="no-truck-deliveries">
            <h4>No Truck</h4>
            <ul 
                cdkDropList 
                [cdkDropListData]="deliveries" 
                cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" 
                [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="truckIds"
                (cdkDropListDropped)="onDeliveryDrop($event)" 
                id="no-trucks"
                class="no-truck">
                <li 
                    cdkDrag
                    *ngFor="let delivery of deliveries"
                    class="delivery-item"
                    (click)="choose(delivery)">
                    <div class="delivery-name">
                        {{ delivery.State }} - {{ delivery.DestinationTR1 }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="delivery-time">
                        {{ delivery.Delivery }}
                    </div>
                    <ul 
                        cdkDropList 
                        [cdkDropListData]="delivery.Packages" 
                        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="deliveryIds" 
                        cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"  
                        (cdkDropListDropped)="onPackageDrop($event)" 
                        id="delivery-{{ delivery.ID }}">
                        <li 
                            cdkDrag
                            *ngFor="let package of delivery.Packages"
                            [ngClass]="package.Type == 'Urgent' ? 'package-item urgent' : 'package-item'"
                            (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); choose(package)">
                            Pack #{{ package.ID }}<br>
                            {{ package.Type }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="width-20 truck-datas">
        <div class="action-buttons">
            <button class="btn">Import</button>
            <button class="btn">Export</button>
        </div>
        <div class="element-datasets">
            <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let key of choosedKeys()">
                    <th [hidden]="isItObject(choosed[key])">{{ key }}</th>
                    <td [hidden]="isItObject(choosed[key])">{{ choosed[key] }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="action-buttons">
            <button class="btn" (click)="doRecalcTime()">Recalculate Time</button>
            <button class="btn" (click)="doRecalcOrder()">Recalculate Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement mentioned scenario's based on the type of `event.container.data`.

So for *1. A package to be directly dropped inside truck*:

In pseudo code:

```
if type of event.container.data === package and type of event.previousContainer is === truck

   Add package to delivery then add delivery to truck
```

And for 2. Delivery in delivery

```
if type of event.container.data === delivery and type of event.previousContainer === delivery

   for each package from delivery add package to new delivery
```

Seems like something you can use Typescripts `instanceof` for. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards

Comment: OK, i need to try out this ... but how i will know from which Delivery the package is dragged .... and in which truck the package is dropped....as container data will provide drop element data not from which it picked up

Comment: What is previousContainer about then?

Comment: If i console log ```event.previousContainer.data``` it shows array of packages in previous delivery from which package drag and opposite in ```event.container.data``` it shows array of packages in current delivery in which package drop....but i am unable to access delivery data ... that is my concern

Comment: But this information is in ```trucks```, right? So you need a way to identify this delivery from ```trucks```.

Comment: In case of delivery from `trucks` but in case of package ```deliveries```

Comment: But these ```deliveries``` are in different trucks, so you'll need to iterate through all trucks to find the package and related delivery. This sounds like you have to filter and find items in arrays. Maybe a library like lodash (https://lodash.com) can help you. I find it very difficult to imagine what happens in your code. If you can provide a working sample in Stackblitz I would be able to look into it more.

Comment: Actually i was looking if we can get the element from angular itself anyways, i will check for that....thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198291/discussion-between-rajat-sharma-and-lnrdnl).